# Make ActiveAdmin select input display in a tree structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree, activeadmin, ancestry

I have a Categories model (HABTM) that has an infinite number of categories and subcategories. I was was rolling my own solution before but I realize now that I am going to have to use Ancestry gem to get this working. When I did my own solution I was able to build a tree because I had a field in my called top_level_category so I knew where to start and a parent_id so I could find my way down the tree. With Ancestry there is just the one string type column to build from. Is there already a solution out there so that I can easy visually select a category and know where where it is in the tree?

I have tried to to activeadmin-sortable-tree gem and can get it to work on the categories index page but not when adding a new category.

```
sortable tree: true,
           sorting_attribute: :name,
           parent_method: :parent,
           children_method: :children,
           roots_method: :roots


form do |f|
        f.inputs "Category", as: :sortable do
          f.input :parent_id, :as => :select, :collection => ItemsCategory.all.map {|u| [u.name, u.id]}
          f.input do
            label :name # item content
            actions
          end
          f.input :name
        end
        f.actions
        f.semantic_errors
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you want to exactly, but if you would like to group the collection of the select in the form according to the tree, try this: option_groups_from_collection_for_select

See more: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/option_groups_from_collection_for_select